# How to write tr:nth-child(even) in ScalaTags?

Tags: css, scala, scalatags

Let's have this simple css:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

**How to write it in ScalaTags?**

I was expecting to see something like `tr.nthChild`, but there are only `firstChild`, `lastChild` and `onlyChild`.

Answer (score 0):

It [doesn't look like ScalaTags provides it](https://github.com/lihaoyi/scalatags/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=nth-child&type=).

We can write our own though:

```
object Foo extends StyleSheet {

  implicit class CreatorWrapper(val creator: Creator) extends AnyVal {
    def nthChildEven: Creator = nthChild("even")
    def nthChild(arg: String): Creator = creator.pseudoExtend(s"nth-child($arg)")
  }

  val foo = cls.nthChildEven(
    backgroundColor := "red"
  )
}
```

Or if you don't want the implicit class:

```
object Foo extends StyleSheet {
  val foo = cls.pseudoExtend(s"nth-child(even)")(
    backgroundColor := "red"
  )
}
```